# Преобразовать код программы на Assembler в правильный вид, для создания com-программы

Tags: ассемблер

К сожалению нету возможности проверить этот код, потому будут рад если кто-то скажет правильно ли я написал код для создания com-программы, или имеются ошибки.

```
sgcode segment para 'code'
assume cs:sgcode, ds:sgcode, ss:sgcode, es:sgcode
org 100h
begin: jmp label1
 jmp label1
text db "It will be probably my first program. $" 
label1: 
 mov ax, cs 
 mov ds, ax
 mov cx, 25
 lea dx, text
 mov ah, 09
 int 21h
 mov ah, 4ch
 int 21h
sgcode ends
end begin
```

Comment: 1) Скажите, пожалуйста, кто вам внушил, что com должен начинаться с jmp? 2) в com ds=cs=es=ss по умолчанию 3) *нету возможности проверить этот код* - так найдите... заодно и учебник почитайте.

Comment: В методичке написано "Команда JMP (безусловный переход) используется для обхода области данных." Но там в примере есть область с данными, а у меня нет. Тут я конечно не подумал сразу.

Comment: У вас тоже есть область с данными: строка `text`.  Но нет никакой причины размещать данные *перед* кодом. Разместите их *после* кода - и ничего перепрыгивать не придётся.